# How to sort an array of struct in C?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, struct, qsort

here i'm again.
I had a problem while i was trying to sort an array of struct in c, i know that my code is not good enough but don't be rude with me please!

I tried changing function parameters but i'm exhausted and i'm sure that i'm going to do more errors if i continue, so i need your help.

Here the full code of my program
https://pastebin.com/p28EbY8i

```
// I've 2 struct 

typedef struct{     // Not used in this function
    int id;
    char * nome;
    char * presidente;
    char * allenatore;
} squadra;

typedef struct{     // I've an array of this type of data
        int id;
        char * nome;
        char * cognome;
        int eta;
        char * ruolo;
        squadra team;
        char * college;
        int td;
    } giocatore;

// This is what i wrote for my function

size_t ordina_classifica(size_t sz, giocatore array[]){  //sz is the array 
                                                         //size
    giocatore temp;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < sz; ++i){
        for(size_t j = i + 1; j < sz; ++j){
            if(array[i].td > array[j].td){

                temp.id = array[i].id;
                temp.nome = array[i].nome;
                temp.cognome = array[i].cognome;
                temp.eta = array[i].eta;
                temp.ruolo = array[i].ruolo;
                temp.team.nome = array[i].team.nome;
                temp.college = array[i].college;
                temp.td = array[i].td;

                array[i].id = array[j].id;
                array[i].nome = array[j].nome;
                array[i].cognome = array[j].cognome;
                array[i].eta = array[j].eta;
                array[i].ruolo = array[j].ruolo;
                array[i].team.nome = array[j].team.nome;
                array[i].college = array[j].college;
                array[i].td = array[j].td;

                array[j].id = temp.id;
                array[j].nome = temp.nome;
                array[j].cognome = temp.cognome;
                array[j].eta = temp.eta;
                array[j].ruolo = temp.ruolo;
                array[j].team.nome = temp.team.nome;
                array[j].college = temp.college;
                array[j].td = temp.td;
            }
        }
    }
    return 2;  // I need this for the rest of the code (in case of sort 
                   // success)
}

//I need to sort my array by the data 'td' that is a integer but for now my //compiler don't print errors, but only crash when i try to select this //function.
```

Comment: Can you use `qsort`?

Comment: I don't know it, how can i use it and how it will work in this case?

Comment: I would suggest you to start with reading its [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort)

Comment: Post how `ordina_classifica()` is called.  "sz is the array size" hint that the calling code may be in error.  See [mcve]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the standard function `qsort` declared in the header `<stdlib.h>`

But before using it you have to define a function that will compare elements of the array.

```
int cmp( const void *a, const void *b )
{
    const giocatore *left  = ( const giocatore * )a;
    const giocatore *right = ( const giocatore * )b;

    return ( right->td < left->td ) - ( left->td < right->td );
}
```

and then call qsort like

```
qsort( array, sz, sizeof( giocatore ), cmp );
```

where `array` is the name of your array of structures, `sz` is the size of the array.

If you want for example to sort the array by the data member `cognome` that points to a string then the comparison function can look even simpler

```
int cmp( const void *a, const void *b )
{
    const giocatore *left  = ( const giocatore * )a;
    const giocatore *right = ( const giocatore * )b;

    return strcmp( left->cognome, right->cognome );
}
```

Of course the name of the comparison function may be any you like. So you may define several comparison functions with different names as for example `sort_by_td`, `sort_by_cognome` and so on.

Comment: OP's sort attempt is _stable_.  `qsort()` is not specified to be [stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Stable_sorts).

Comment: @Bjorn A `right->td - left->td` may overflow (undefined behavior) - sort incorrectly.  `( right->td < left->td ) - ( left->td < right->td )` does not have that problem.